# HashMaps fast enough?

Tags: java, performance, opengl, hashmap, lwjgl

Im building my own little Opengl Library based on Lwjgl. In the moment im using HashMaps for storing things like render objects, scens or shader programs, because i want to have on Class the user can see, and there create methods to modify, create, i dont know... other objects or classes which are protected.
So, to explain this:

There is a class called "ShaderProgram". But instead to allow the user to create one, with ShaderProgram s = new ShaderProgram(...); , i create a method in my "main class", called "createShaderProgram", give it the params, create a shader program and put it to the hashMap called shaderPrograms, with a name the user decides. for example with MyClass.createShaderProgram("particle_shader", ...) i can create a shader for my particles, and then with MyClass.binShaderProgram("particle_shader") or something like this, i can use it.

BUT: Is this fast enough? Or are there other reasons to change it to int indicies, or, completely allow the user to use all the classes? Because for example im creating the render objects like this, too, and in each frame to do MyClass.getRenderObject("ACube").move(...) ... can i do this? What do you think about this?

Comment: A hashmap is quite fast (Average case O(1)). With that said you should consider your API design here. Do you want users to possibly have access to those classes so they can store a ShaderProgram how they wish? Then maybe the `createShaderProgram` should really be a [Factoy Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), so users can control their `ShaderProgram`'s.

Comment: thank you, ill think about this.

Answer (score 2):

Access complexity time for hash table is O(n) in the worst case: 
[Time Complexity of HashMap methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577998/time-complexity-of-hashmap-methods)

So Yes, I would say that if performance accessing your objects collections is so important you should use 1:1 indexed collections like arrays.

Comment: You mean best case O(1). Worst case is O(n) (all entries hash to the same bucket)

Comment: @JimGarrison Didn't I write that?